# Inner Join not working properly in Mysql tables

Tags: inner-join

I have two tables; 1. Details, 2. Additional

Structure of these tables are as follows:

```
Details:
| id | name | start_date | end_date | city | ....

Additional:
| id | event_id | ratings | reviews | visits | total_points | ...
```

Here, id from 'details' and 'event_id' from 'additional' have same value, so I can connect both tables. In `details` I have 26 cols and in `Additional` I have 18 cols. As per reviews and ratings received from users and total visits on pages, I give them points which eventually adds in `total_points` field. So when I fetch data from these tables, I first sort them by city name, start date and end date, and then I check the total points they have got and arrange them in decreasing order(best to worst).

What I have done so far is as below:

> $con->query("SELECT * FROM details INNER JOIN additional ON
>   details.id = additional.event_id WHERE city = '$currentLocation' AND
>   (sDate ='$todayDate' OR (sDate <='$todayDate' AND
>   eDate >= '$todayDate')) ORDER BY additional.total_points*1 DESC");

But it's not fetching rows properly, id from details is matching with id in additional, not event_id.

Any help would be appreciated!

TIA

Comment: Can you show some sample input and output?  The query looks like it should work.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your attention, but I have just now fixed the issue. Problem was, in both tables one field is there with same name called `id`. So when I was printing `id`, it was taking value from `additional` not from `details`. So I changed that, and now my code is good.

Comment: Please post this as an answer to your problem and mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Query is absolutely fine, but the problem is, both tables have one column with same name i.e. `id`. So when we print the values from database, the column `id` fetches value from `additional` table, not from `details`.

So better change the name of column in `additional` table.